# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly won't connect to wifi network unless it's 5G

Tags: networking, 20.04

Okay, so recently I got a new router and have been experiencing a really weird issue where at random times of the day (and at random intervals) my laptop will disconnect itself from my network and refuse to reconnect unless I'm using the 5G network. My laptop's an HP Pavilion x360 I got a little over a year ago and hasn't had any issues like this until recently.

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: 5G (mobile - 5th generation) or WiFi 5**GHz**?

Comment: WiFi 5GHz I believe. Definitely not mobile, it's like... (NetworkName) and (NetworkName)-5G. For some reason, I'm unable to connect to my normal network right now.

Before you ask: I already tried to upgrade/update my computer through the command line.

Comment: OK, though so. Why aren't you using (or don't wan to use) the 5GHz network then? It's likely to be much less crowded than thew 2.4GHz band.

Comment: As stupid as this is going to sound, it's a lack of understanding on how it works for me. I don't want to use the 5GHz network if it's going to somehow cost more money and usually the 2.4GHz band is enough to keep me satisfied anyways.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with price! You pay for your internet access, not for the way your router provides such access.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: (Deleted original comment.)
Okay, so upon checking the logs I think I might've found what I was looking for but I'm not sure which part I can (or should) post. (I'm open to adding what it says to my original post.)

Comment: If you don't want to use the 5Ghz band, you should be able to disable it using the router's control panel

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your new router autoselects the band it uses based on an autonegotiation between your wireless device and your router. Between them, they decide the fastest speed that both can reliably use. In most cases, that will be 5 gHz.

I can think of no reason whatever to not prefer 5 gHz. In fact, the 2.4 gHz band suffers from interference from many places including bluetooth, cordless phones and even microwave ovens!

https://community.netgear.com/t5/General-WiFi-Routers-Non/Microwave-Interference/td-p/1173647

If you insist on using the interference-ridden, slower 2.4 gHz channel, simply go into the administration pages of the router and rename both bands, something like talia2.4 and talia5 or similar.

While you are in there, I suggest that you check all the settings. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

None of the six devices in my home are connected to 2.4 gHz.